# Trigger jQuery when a vanilla js function has been fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a jQuery function that catches changes on a input field and add it to a variable.

The input field is also held up on a vanilla js based API lib, that I cant convert to jQuery.
The lib is an address API, so people can select a address, and that wont trigger my jQuery function. I therefore thought of a workaround, where my jQuery is watching my vanilla js, to see when it's fired, and fire my jQuery function right after.

My jQuery function:

```
$('#billing_address_1').on('input',function(e){
    let addressValue = $('#billing_address_1').val();
});
```

My vanilla js function:

```
"use strict"

dawaAutocomplete.dawaAutocomplete( document.getElementById("billing_address_1"), {
    select: function(selected) {
        document.getElementById("valgtadresse").innerHTML = selected.tekst;
    }
});
```

All solutions I've been able to search for, has been requiring that I use .trigger() on my vanilla js in this case. They've not been made for the mix of these two js alternatives. Can I do it in a more proper way?

Comment: What's wrong with `select: function(selected) { $("#valgtadresse").trigger("change"); }`  If you're using jquery then you can use it anywhere.   That's not changing your drawAutocomplete plugin.   If you don't want jquery in your `select:` then do the same, but with a [javascript event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548330/2181514)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to touch your fields with trigger you can try event emitter pattern which is quite popular in node. Here you keep an object as notifier on which you call event and also hook listeners for that event. It is basically a [Pub-Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern a simple implementation of which in vanilla javascript is available over [here](https://gist.github.com/mudge/5830382) by [mudge](https://github.com/mudge) or you might also try any alternatives if you find

```
// KEEP THIS SOMEWHERE IN OUTER SCOPE 
let bird = new EventEmitter()


//THEN - hook on any event you name it
bird.on('tweet', (val)=>{
  console.log(val)  
  addressValue = val
})

//THEN - emit that named event wherever you might need
dawaAutocomplete.dawaAutocomplete( document.getElementById("billing_address_1"), {
    select: function(selected) {
        document.getElementById("valgtadresse").innerHTML = selected.tekst;
        bird.emit('tweet', selected.tekst);
    }
});
```